# Textures look extremely weird

Tags: texturing

So apparently the textures look weird on the phone model I'm trying to make. I just want it on the screen not on the whole phone. How do you make the image texture stay on one face but not on all faces? Its hard to fix it for me.[image: my phone model.]

Comment: in Edit mode, select the faces that are supposed to have the another material, in the Material panel, create a new one and assign it to these faces with the Assign button

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the UV, named so because XY is used for 3d localisation and UV is just a planar representation of the unwrap on a model. So work your UV correctly through the UV editor, in this case you should just select all the faces for the screen and press U then 'unwrap' or 'unwrap from view' if your are in front of the object in a precise way as when selecting the view with numpad numbers. Also when you are done with that you can select the other faces and assign a different material to it.

Comment: Ok. Sounds simple.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Yvain.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: But every face on the phone has a phone screen...why is that? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You might surely have unwraping by default now. Just repeat the procedure.

Comment: Ok will try again.

Comment: I am stuck like hell! Why is it still looking weird? I tried it and tried it....refuses to work with meh.

Comment: It is because every face of the model is mapped to the entire image instead of having all the faces divided between the entire image in a correct way. Check in the uv image editor.